Short exact sequences in (rigid) abelian tensor categories.
If $0 \to A \overset{f}{\to} \mathbf{1} \overset{g}{\to} B \to 0$ is a short exact sequence in an rigid abelian tensor category with identity object $\mathbf{1}$, then also $0 \to A \otimes X \to \mathbf{1} \otimes X \to B \to 0$ is a short exact sequence.
So we know that $\text{im}(f \otimes \text{id}:A \otimes X \to \mathbf{1} \otimes X) \simeq \text{ker}(g \otimes \text{id}:\mathbf{1} \otimes X \to B \otimes X)$. Why does it then follow that $0 \to A \otimes X \to X \to B \otimes X \to 0$ is also a short exact sequence? I know this is a naive question, but I am finding it hard to show why it should hold.

The argument combines a standard fact about duals with a standard fact about abelian categories:

If an object $X$ in a symmetric monoidal category has a dual then the functor $(-) \otimes X$ has both a left and a right adjoint, namely $(-) \otimes X^{\ast}$. That means it preserves both limits and colimits.

A functor between abelian categories which preserves both limits and colimits is exact, meaning it preserves exact sequences. (It suffices for it to preserve finite direct sums, kernels, and cokernels.)


The first is an exercise in relating duals to adjoints while the second is an exercise in unpacking the definition of exactness.

Dear Qiaochu: Yes, I know about these two facts, but those two facts just gives you that $0 \to A \otimes X \to \mathbf{1} \otimes X \to B \otimes X \to 0$ is exact (I think). But how do we then go to $0 \to A \otimes X \to X \to B \otimes X \to 0$ being exact?

@Ben123: $1$ is the unit, so by definition $1 \otimes X \cong X$...

Yeah, I'm well aware. I don't see how that explains much, tbh.

I mean, it is easy to see that then $0 \to A \otimes X \overset{f' := \phi \circ f \otimes \text{id}}{\to} X \overset{g' := g \otimes \text{id} \circ \phi^{-1}}{\to} B \otimes X \to 0$, where $\phi:\mathbf{1} \otimes X \simeq X$, is such that $g' \circ f' = 0$. But then we also have to show that $\text{im}(f') \simeq \text{ker}(g')$.

@Ben123: are you asking why exactness is preserved by the replacement of $1 \otimes X$ by the isomorphic $X$? This is a very general feature of how limits and colimits work. Suppose more generally that $A \to B \to C$ is a sequence, and $A' \to B' \to C'$ is an isomorphic sequence, meaning we have three isomorphisms $\phi_A : A \to A', \phi_B : B \to B', \phi_C : C \to C'$ making the obvious diagram commute. Then the first sequence is exact iff the second one is. This boils down concretely to some statements about how kernels and cokernels behave if you pre-and post-compose with isomorphisms.

Yep, that answer is closer to what I was looking for. Do you have any references regarding "This boils down concretely to some statements about how kernels and cokernels behave if you pre-and post-compose with isomorphisms"? Note that I am quite new to the concept of limits/colimits, hence my very naive questions.
(Thanks again).

Something like this will probably be discussed in any introductory text on homological algebra but I don't know a specific reference (I'm not a huge fan of any of the ones I've looked at). In any case this is a good exercise and I don't think it's too bad; if you get stuck you can ask a new question about it.
